# How to filter out the list of duplicate names using Stored Procedure in SQL?

Tags: sql

I have a table like that

[image]

Now, I want to print out the MaSach with the most repetitions(detail:M201)

What should I do? Thanks

Comment: Tag with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `group by` and limit to one row somehow.  In Standard SQL this looks like:

```
select MaSach
from t
group by MaSach
order by count(*) desc
offset 0 row fetch first 1 row only;
```

Not all databases support the `offset`/`fetch` clause.  It might be `limit` or `select top` or something else.

Comment: Oh Thanks you. It's work! what if i want to filter out the least occured value.

Comment: @ChenArgon . . . Then you have a *different* question and that should be asked as a new question.  This question has been answered.